# Does Kinzie ever use her safe word ingame in Saints Row?

Tags: saints-row-the-third, saints-row-iv

So Kinzie Kensington mentions in the introduction dialogue for the mission in which you free Zimos that her safe word is "Teacup". I checked the wiki, and the only mention is in her banter with Tanya between missions, after the latter told her she would be a major draw at a brothel.

Is this the only time she uses her safe word, or does she use it at other times as well? I sort-of remember her using it in my playthroughs, and I didn't really bother with homies.

Comment: My personal experience indicates no. I haven't played SR4.

Comment: She doesn't use it in Gat Out of Hell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I extracted and listened to all of Kinzie's dialog, and while she has a lot of it (752 clips), there aren't too many uses of her safe word. Which would mean it is likely a good safe word as it isn't something she says in ever day conversation. Below are references to her safe word.

### Kinzie

- In conversation with Tanya about the brothel
- As a reaction, likely to surprise or injury or something
- > Someday we should probably name this ship.  I've been giving it a lot of thought and I think we need a name that confuses our enemies by seeming innocuous to the uninformed.  That's why I'd vote for Tea Cup.

### Others

- ["Hello Teacup"](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/Hello_Teacup) is the name of the mission where you find Kinzie

Comment: Thanks for the effort. If noone else gives an answer, I'll accept this one by tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

In Gat out of Hell, Kinzie *does* actually use her safe word a couple of times, but it's a random response spawn in each action, triggered by different events...

**Easy Kill**
"Should've said 'teacup'."

**Burn or Explosion Damage**
"Teacup!  Teacup!"

Kinzie has to be one of my favourite homies, and touches like that are a lot of fun in GOOH. I'd also point out that you get a *very* different reaction from the twins (Kiki & Viola) if you approach them with Kinzie, as Kinzie and Viola (as it happens) have bonded between SRTT and SRIV.